# What was the biggest miracle in the time of the Megilla?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There were many miracles in the time of the Megilla. What was the biggest one?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 11):

It mentions in the Megilla "מחשבת המן" - Haman had a computer.

Which type of computer could he have? The Gemara says that Haman is connected to "Hamin Heitz" - Haman is a tree. The only tree computer that exists is an Apple, Therefore, Haman was an Apple.

Now, Apples are known to be stable computers. Yet, Haman was still able to be hung.

Comment: Which, incidentally, is why the Baker (in the Egyptian Jail) was hung. You see, he was having too many dreams. Dreams are called " **Chalo** mos" which shares the same root as " **Chalo** nos" (which is particularly connected to Challa, which again is in the domain of the Baker). "Chalonos" are Windows, and everyone knows how easy it is to "hang" Windows.

Comment: You forgot about Apricot computers!  Also from a tree. (Apple II days clone).

Comment: +1. We can probably extend this to some other characters in the Megillah as well. Achashverosh had סריסים = eunuchs = Unix; Mordechai had DOS (פתשגן כתב הדת), and Esther - not sure, but it definitely wasn't DOS (אשר לא כדת).

Comment: @Alex Mordechai was Linux (penguin), after all, he **did** wear a black hat and white shirt.

Comment: Note his computer was female.

Answer (score 8):

> "In the third year of his reign, he made a feast unto all his princes and his servants; the army of Persia and Media, the nobles and princes of the provinces, being before him.  When he showed the riches of his glorious kingdom and the honour of his excellent majesty, many days, a hundred and eighty days." -Esther 1:3-4

One hundred and eighty days of drunken debauchery, and yet there is no mention of anyone having a hangover.  That is truly a miracle.

Comment: On a more serious note, maybe that's why Achashverosh seems to do whatever anyone tells him to do.

Comment: @AriA Boo. Purim Torah only.

Comment: @ Seth J. haha. sorry