# How did my rabbi kasher his iPhone?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My local Orthodox rabbi regularly sends me emails about upcoming events, minyanim, etc.  I notice that at the bottom of each message it says "Sent from my kosher iPhone".

How did he kasher his phone?  Did he toivel it in a mikvah, pour boiling water over it, heat it up to the temperature it was fabricated at?  Should I do this to my phone too?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated).

Comment: its not referring to it as a utensil,but as an apple which is kosher

Comment: @sam Before the iPhone 4 it was orlah

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55508/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69265/759

Answer (score 10):

An item is kashered in the same way that it became treif. Your rabbi sends fiery words of Torah over the IPhone so that it became kosher through libun (burning). This is the most intense way of kashering something (like an oven).

Comment: Is this Libbun Kal of Libbun Chamur?

Comment: @doubleaa Torah is obviously chamur the program,us on the net is so bad it requires the most

Answer (score 6):

Many people, esp. in U.S. believe that the way something becomes kosher is that a rabbi blesses it. I've heard this from many secular Jews as well as numerous Gentiles.

Where do these people get this notion? From the internet, of course! And, you know what they say, if it's on the internet, then it MUST be true!

Well, there you go! He's a rabbi. He blessed his own iPhone. Therefore, it's kosher!

Answer (score 5):

Haman [was](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15074/14326) an Apple, and the general consensus was that Haman [wasn't](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14923/14326) kosher, as he was made up of butter and meat.

But... We have since invented margarine, and as our [Chief](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/alltime/judaism/2011-05-10/200#200) Rabbi, [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/200/gershon-gold) [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14929/14326), Haman was made out of *margarine*, and not butter. Therefore, he (and Apples) are Kosher.

So to avoid Maaras Ayin, your Rabbi made sure to stress that the iPhone was kosher.

Answer (score 4):

He actually "kashered" it by getting a bluetooth.

It's [well known](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80774/4794) that G-d doesn't want us holding iPhones. However, as the verse there says, the problem is that it's ביד אדם, in the *hand* of man. However, if you use a bluetooth and keep your iPhone on the table, then it's OK.

So your Rabbi is telling everyone that he has connected his iPhone to bluetooth and is therefore using it in a kosher way.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.  His iPhone does not need to be kashered.  iPhones are kosher from birth and remain so until made treif, or until they are stepped on or die from other causes.  Your rabbi is just saying that he did not do anything w his iPhone to treif it up.  (You may need to post another question to find out how to treif up an iPhone.)

Comment: You can easily traif an Iphone by placing it in an Android oven.